# Como obtener botton y top

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dom

Estoy usando angularjs y debo obtener el top y el botton del scroll y el top y botton del div que contiene al scroll, todo eso para saber si el scroll esta completamente abajo, 
**mi objetivo es saber si el scroll esta abajo**
, con el siguiente codigo obtengo para el div y como obtengo para el scroll?

```
document.querySelector('#divScroll').getBoundingClientRect()
```

nota: no debo usar jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buenas, con esto puede obtener el alto de la barra de scroll:

```
var intElemScrollHeight = element.scrollHeight;
```

Para mas referencia, te recomiendo este artículo:

https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollHeight

Otra propiedad a utilizar es scrollTop:

https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollTop

Este es un ejemplo básico de como detectar que llegaste al final del scroll:

https://plnkr.co/edit/UP9Wvj6BMLhNXreVDIR9?p=preview

Tu implementación puede cambiar un poco, dependiendo de tu estructura de html

Espero que esto sea de utilidad, en caso contrario, no dudes en volver a preguntar.

Comment: como puedo saber si el scroll esta abajo?

Comment: Con la propiedad scrollTop sabés donde está el scroll posicionado (https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollTop), ahí podés revisar con respecto a la ventana, o con respecto al scroll, dependiendo como tengas armado tu html. Este es un ejemplo que encontré que podés revisar (http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/gWD66/). Saludos

Comment: esta usando jquery y eso esta prohibido, no debo usar jquery

Comment: En unos minutos te armo un ejemplo en angular, pero las propiedades son de javascript puro, no te preocupes.

Comment: @Rubén pero estaria bien una respuesta en angular o js puro nada de jquery

Comment: ya ví que algo incluyes

Comment: @KN_ un favor mas como puedo preguntar si llego abajo desde  una funcion? me refiero que ahora se activa moviendo el scroll, pero ahora necesito que lo active una funcion

Comment: Te parece crear un chat y lo vemos ahí? Así no dejamos tantos comentarios

Comment: @KN_ he creado un chat https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62009/angularscroll unete porfavor